# Variables substitution in a B-Spline function

Tags: splines

I have the following identity mapping expressed by tensor-product B-spline basis functions:

```
pts = {{-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {-1,1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
k = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 1};
nBasis = Sqrt[Length[pts]];
basisU = Table[BSplineBasis[{1, k}, i, u], {i, 0, nBasis - 1}];
basisV = Table[BSplineBasis[{1, k}, i, v], {i, 0, nBasis - 1}];
tensorProductBasis = Table[basisU[[i]] basisV[[j]], {j, 1, nBasis}, {i, 1, nBasis}];
tensorProductBasis = ArrayReshape[%, {1, nBasis^2}][[1]];
map = Sum[pts[[i]] tensorProductBasis[[i]], {i, 1, nBasis^2}];
```

I have also NURBS representation of a circle:

```
pts = {{.5, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {.5, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {.5, 0}};
w = {1, .5, .5, 1, .5, .5, 1};
k = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1};
circle = BSplineFunction[pts, SplineWeights -> w, SplineKnots -> k];
```

I need to substitute the identity map variables $u$ and $v$ by the first and second components of B-spline function representing a circle and get expression depending on one variable only. When I am trying to do like this:

```
newMap = map /. {u -> circle[t][[1]], v -> circle[t][[2]]};
```

I get an error:

```
Part::partw: "Part 2 of BSplineFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>][t] does not exist
```

I would appreciate any advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first try to rephrase the question to be sure we understand each other correctly.

You have a curve in the plane (`circle` in this case; cf. Fig. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVy4r.png)).

[image: Before applying <code>map</code>.]

You deform a portion of the plane enclosing the curve (i.e., `circle`) with `map` and you would like to see what the curve looks like afterwards. (I took a `map` different from identity to demonstrate the difference in Fig. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgFoA.png).)

[image: After applying <code>map</code>.]

Now to the answer. The first possibility (trying to minimize changes in the code) is just to change the definition of `newMap` as follows.

```
newMap[t_] := Module[{}, u = circle[t][[1]]; v = circle[t][[2]]; map]
```

This way we locally change the values of `u` and `v` to be what we need them to.

However, I am not very happy with this solution -- your `map` is a hard-wired to be a function of variables `u` and `v`. If you change `u` or `v` elsewhere in your notebook, you can destroy your result (as an example, set `u` to .7 and observe the whole thing crumble).

What I would propose instead is to rework your code to use built-in function `BSplineFunction`.

```
pts = {{-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {-1,1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
k = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 1};
nBasis = Sqrt[Length[pts]];
(* We need a two-dimensional array of control points: *)
CPs = Table[pts[[(i - 1)*nBasis + j]], {i, 1, nBasis}, {j, 1, nBasis}];
map = BSplineFunction[CPs, SplineDegree -> 1, SplineKnots -> k]
```

Now keeping your definition of `circle`, all you need to add is the definition of `newMap`.

```
newMap[t_]:=map[circle[t][[1]],circle[t][[2]]]
```

Of course, whether this is a good solution depends on what you are going to do with it later on. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that you should have also used the NURBS representation for constructing the circle as well, since you already did it for the map. Let me first show a better way to build your mapping:

```
pts = {{-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
k = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 1};
nBasis = Sqrt[Length[pts]];
basisU = Table[BSplineBasis[{1, k}, i, u], {i, 0, nBasis - 1}];
basisV = Table[BSplineBasis[{1, k}, i, v], {i, 0, nBasis - 1}];
map[u_, v_] = Flatten[Outer[Times, basisV, basisU]].pts;
```

Do something similar for the circle:

```
cpts = {{1/2, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1/2, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1/2, 0}};
cw = {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1};
ck = {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1};
basisT = Table[BSplineBasis[{2, ck}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[cpts]}];
circ[t_] = (cw basisT).cpts/(cw.basisT);
```

Then, evaluate

```
ParametricPlot[map @@ circ[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

and you should get the same figure as the one in grbl's answer. The differentiation you mentioned in a comment is expediently done as well:

```
ParametricPlot[D[map @@ circ[t], t] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: kidney]

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are doing. The `BSplineFunction` needs to be evaluated a point. You could try

```
ClearAll[newMap]
newMap[t_] := map /. {u -> (circle[t] )[[1]], v -> (circle[t] )[[2]]};
ParametricPlot[newMap[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Then I need to separate $x$- and $y$-components of the `newMap`, differentiate them w.r.t. $t$ and calculate the values of derivatives at a particular point. When I define functions `derX[t_] := (newMap'[t])[[1]]` and  `derY[t_] := (newMap'[t])[[2]]` and try to calculate their values at a particular parameter value (e.g.  `derX[0.5]` and `derY[0.5]`), I get unreasonable results.